# submit ajax form with link not function

Tags: jquery

i try submit my form using link but the ajax is not function :

```
<form id="store_relation" action="store_relation.php" method="post" name="store_relation" >
        <input type="hidden" name="store_id" value="<?php echo $row['store_id']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
</form>
<li class="online_users"><a id="online_form"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></a></li>

<script type='text/javascript' language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#online_form').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the link's default behaviour
         $('#store_relation').ajaxForm( {
            success: function() { 
            alert('hey');
            } 
        }); 
    });
 }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ajaxSubmit()` instead of `ajaxForm()`. According to the [Form API](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#api)
ajaxForm

> Prepares a form to be submitted via AJAX by adding all of the
>   necessary event listeners. It does not submit the form. Use ajaxForm
>   in your document's ready function to prepare your form(s) for AJAX
>   submission. ajaxForm takes zero or one argument. The single argument
>   can be either a callback function or an Options Object.

ajaxSubmit

> Immediately submits the form via AJAX. In the most common use case
>   this is invoked in response to the user clicking a submit button on
>   the form. ajaxSubmit takes zero or one argument. The single argument
>   can be either a callback function or an Options Object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#online_form').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the link's default behaviour
         $('#store_relation').ajaxSubmit( {
            success: function() { 
            alert('hey');
            } 
        }); 
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`ajaxForm()` does not submit the form, nor does your link. De API @ http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api states

> Prepares a form to be submitted via AJAX by adding all of the necessary event listeners. It does not submit the form.

So your values are never submitted, and so you never get into the "succes" state.

You need to submit the form yourself, or use a submit-button in stead of a link. Note that not all browsers accept an `<a>` without an `href`